# Twilio SMS have status delivered but don`t receive to phone

Tags: twilio

Twilio SMS have status delivered but don`t receive to phone

I try to send other phone numbers but have the same problem

Comment: can u please tag question correctly, how is this related to Go and how is this related to any coding issue ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not clear what you are asking. Please review [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how-to-create-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer

Comment: How this question is related to golang?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the Twilio Support page about [Troubleshooting Undelivered Twilio SMS Messages](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181868-Troubleshooting-Undelivered-Twilio-SMS-Messages);

> Twilio's Support team can help investigate what went wrong with
>   delivering your message. Please collect 3 or more message SIDs in your
>   [SMS logs](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/logs) from the last 24 hours that show these same issues, and 
>   [Open a support request](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact).

Answer (score 0):

I find the reason 
for other operators don`t like the same world`s for me is "points"

I delete "points" from message and SMS receive